# How can i add two buttons to a single datagrid column dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagrid

**button code**

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn btn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();  
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(btn);
```

I'm using WinForms App, here this way I add two buttons, but I want these two button should be place in single column only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a custom column. Look at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fb61s43.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730882%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for some examples.

Comment: Thank you for your response sir.I created the custom colomn and i add two buttons to that but those are displaying in separate columns,but i need them in one column.what should i do?

Comment: See the "DataGridViewRadioButtonColumn" example here. I think that's what you want. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730882%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom DataGridView column.

Here's an article that can help:
http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/35186

Comment: Thank you for your response sir.I created the custom colomn and i add two buttons to that but those are displaying in separate columns,but i need them in one column.what should i do?