# DataGridView Row Compute

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview, row

I'm on a project with C# in visual studio.In my project, there is one gridview and one button under of it. When i click button,i want to calculate total working minutes of my workers in to a last row. I read all similar topics but there is something wrong with my codes.. If you have more/any illustrative example, please help me, i need really help. My deadline is short for the project.

Here is the logic;

```
Sunday   Monday   Tuesday    ........     TOTAL

   10           50            5          ........        65              works like this..
```

Actually i dont want to use only one button under my gridview. I want to use for each worker on each row...

Here is ButtonClick codes but i dont wanna use like this. I need to add template column, which contains buttons for each row. I knew but how ? It always fails, i always get some errors.

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            row.Cells[10].Text = (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[3].Text) + Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[4].Text)).ToString() +
                                 (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[5].Text) + Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[6].Text)).ToString() +
                                 (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[7].Text) + Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[8].Text)).ToString() +
                                 (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[9].Text));
        }
    }
```

Comment: your asking two questions.you should ask one by one.which is your problem?putting button in each row of datagridview or calcuting total working?

Comment: Yes my friend, you are right.
I'm asking that; i want to put button on each rows and when i click the button, i want to calculate total values on that row in to the last row.

Answer (score 0):

To have button on each row you need to use

```
DatagridviewButtonColumn
```

info: [How can i add two buttons to a single datagrid column dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005036/how-can-i-add-two-buttons-to-a-single-datagrid-column-dynamically)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn.aspx

[Define DataGridView Column type Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781007/define-datagridview-column-type-programmatically)

**EDITED:**

You can do like this :

```
 DataGridViewButtonColumn clbt_delet = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
   clbt_delete.HeaderText = "DELETE"
   clbt_delete.Text = "Delete";
   clbt_delete.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
   dataGridView1.Columns.Add(clbt_delete);
```

If you need any other information about that please feel free to say