# Merge two column headers into one column in data grid view C# window form / or two column buttons under one column

Tags: c#, forms, window

I have to place two columns buttons( Edit and Delete) under one columns using C# window form application.
I tried every ways that I searched in every place but nothing work.
Send me help pls.
Merge two column headers also okay then I can set border to none .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67246419/14171304

Answer (score 0):

You can't put two buttons in one column. A column can only be one type (e.g. text, button, checkbox, ...). 

You can create a custom column to do this but I have no idea how this works. I found this: [How can i add two buttons to a single datagrid column dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005036/how-can-i-add-two-buttons-to-a-single-datagrid-column-dynamically)

Comment: thanks . I solved it with cell painting event and make border style to none between two button.